# Flow past a parabolic lamina submerged in a tube. Please see the attached figure

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[image: parabolic profile]

How do I compute the velocity field around the parabolic body using Navier-Stokes? I want to solve it like Poiseuille's law.

I have no slip at the wall boundary and a free shear layer at the boundary between the parabola and the outer fluid.

How do I integrate over the parabolic surface? I am interested in the velocity of the falling film, given the rising velocity of the parabolic body.

Comment: Are the tube and the parabolic body round, or 2-dimensional? You say the "falling film", which seems to make it ambiguous. Is gravity involved? Is the velocity fast or slow (Reynold's number)>

Comment: This view is a section along the x-axis. The tube and parabolic body are both 2-dimensional. The liquid is flowing down with a velocity 'u'. Gravity is involved. Velocity is such that the flow is laminar.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. If I turned a parabolic bullet on a lathe and inserted it into a section of PVC pipe, pointed the whole thing vertically, and then poured honey down it, would that be what you're describing?

Comment: yes that would be it!

Comment: ok, I think i'm starting to get most of this.  I'm not sure about the 'free shear layer'. From what you've written it seems like BC at the parabola is not no-slip.  Also the 'outer fluild' confuses me. Is there more than one fluid at play here?

Comment: the parabola is actually a gas bubble. free shear implies du/dy = 0.